# Is "Not at all" grammatically correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

There was an English question in my English test that confused me a lot.

```
- What if I fail the exam tomorrow?
A: - Be confident.
B: - Not at all. You can make it.
```

I think A is the correct answer but I can't explain why B is wrong. Can you explain to me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: However, the first answer is also wrong. That's not an appropriate answer for the way the question is phrased.

Answer (score 1):

To say "Not at all", there must be a (yes/no) question.

- Do you think that I will fail the exam tomorrow?
- No, not at all. (I do **not** think of it **at all**)